# String formatting for youtube subtitles in python

Tags: python, formatting

I was trying to capture a piece of the subtitle from a youtube video. I scraped the data but now I'm facing difficulty in formatting it. I want to delete the timestamps and extra newlines(\n)
and get it in a nice string format. I want to know the best way to tackle these problems so that in the future I could fetch the properly

the data:

```
what if I told you that the world
0:06
creates 2.5 quintillion bytes of data
0:09
every single day would you believe me
0:12
what if I told you that 90% of all data
0:14
ever created in the history of the world
0:17
sprouted in just the past two years do
0:20
you believe me yet well hold on your
0:22
brains folks because both are very very
0:24
true whether it's the 13 new spotify
0:27
songs or the 600 Wikipedia page edits
0:29
maybe the five hundred and twenty seven
0:31
thousand snapchats or how about sixty
0:34
million texts all of this data is
0:36
created no not just in a day in 60
0:39
```

Comment: Could you please copy the subtitle text directly into your question? It will make it easier for someone to answer your question. Also please include the sample code of how you are pulling the data

Comment: Thanks, @Stephan Actually I just copied the subtitle from youtube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you simply want to remove the timestamp lines, try this regex call:

```
import re

rawSubtitles = """what if I told you that the world
0:06
creates 2.5 quintillion bytes of data
0:09
every single day would you believe me
0:12
what if I told you that 90% of all data
0:14
ever created in the history of the world
0:17
sprouted in just the past two years do
0:20
you believe me yet well hold on your
0:22
brains folks because both are very very
0:24
true whether it's the 13 new spotify
0:27
songs or the 600 Wikipedia page edits
0:29
maybe the five hundred and twenty seven
0:31
thousand snapchats or how about sixty
0:34
million texts all of this data is
0:36
created no not just in a day in 60
0:39
"""

# subtitles = [[],[]]
cleanSubtitle = re.sub(r"\n\d+:\d+\n"," ",rawSubtitles)

print(cleanSubtitle)
```

### Output:

> what if I told you that the world creates 2.5 quintillion bytes of data every single day would you believe me what if I told you that 90% of all data ever created in the history of the world sprouted in just the past two years do you believe me yet well hold on your brains folks because both are very very true whether it's the 13 new spotify songs or the 600 Wikipedia page edits maybe the five hundred and twenty seven thousand snapchats or how about sixty million texts all of this data is created no not just in a day in 60

How it Works:

- \d+ finds a group of digits
- ":" finds colon
- \n finds the new lines on each side of the pattern, ensuring the entire line is just in format of "#:#"
- Then for anything it matches, it replaces it with a space, but could use some other delimiter if you'd prefer

Comment: Thanks @Stephan can you tell me why did you use triple inverted commas.

Comment: If you are referring to the triple back quotes ``` I added to your question, that is just for Stack Overflow formatting so it’s easier to understand your question